# How to specify the "+" (plus) key in a keybinding for Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings

I'm under Windows. Sublime Text by default comes with keybindings for indent (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>) and unindent (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>) commands that due to the (Spanish) key distribution of my keyboard region those keybindings are miserably useless (are very dificult to press, consuming much time).

Then, I'm trying to override those keybindings for which I created a custom `Default.sublime-keymap` file in which I wrote this content:

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl++"], "command": "indent" },
   { "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "unindent" }
]
```

The keybinding for unindent works perfectly and I can still zoom the text out using the default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>keypad_minus</kbd> of the numpad, however, the keybinding for indent command does not work, when I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> key combination the 'Zoom Text In' command (I don't know the exact command name) seems to override my keybinding...

I also tried with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>plus</kbd> combination... obtaining the same result. If I specify <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>keypad_plus</kbd> it works ok with the numpad's plus key, but the plus key I want to set is the normal plus key.

How can I properly define the plus key (not the numpad plus key) in the keybinding?, or a suitable alternative (that does not implies to override/remove the default 'Zomm Text In' keybinding), so this way I can indent with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>plus</kbd>, unindent with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>minus</kbd>, and zoom text in and out with the numpad's plus and minus keys.

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keybinding-with-plus/130/9

Comment: @Jared Menard Thanks but I would clarify that published my question in S.O. just after researching and after reading that thread, in which unfortunately there is any workaround/solution for this problem (more than the tip to use the "keypad_plus" key instead). Thanks anyways for your time trying to find a solution!

Comment: What OS are you using? It could be possible to do the mapping through the OS. If you are on OSX, you could go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts and set something up there.

Comment: If you open the console with `View > Console`, enter `sublime.log_input(True)` and then press the key in question, it will tell you what you need to bind. In all likelyhood it's `ctrl+=` though.

Comment: I'm using Windows. @OdatNurd When I press the plus key, the console outputs this: `chr evt: + (0x2b)`, then I still in the same situation. Maybe you know if there is a way to specify the exact ASCII code when defining the keybinding?, I tried to assign: `"ctrl+(0x2b)"` and similar combinations with no luck.

Comment: If turning on input logging and pressing Control and the + key together tells you it's just `+`, your control key is broken.

Comment: Oh, I thought the thing was to identify the "+" key regardless of whether the ctrl key was hold or not, I didn't expected that the key would be different when the ctrl key is hold, I see, the "Ctrl+plus" combination it is strangely recognized as a ctrl+equals symbol: "control+=", that is the right keybinding syntax... or it seems. Well, putting that keybinding it seems to work as expected. Thankyou!

Comment: Yeah, when it comes to bindings, it wants the keys without regard to the modifiers that might be applied. Since you have to apply `Shift` to get to the `+` character, technically it's the `=` key. Glad you sorted it!

Comment: `Since you have to apply Shift to get to the + character, technically it's the = key` No, its not so obvious the strange input capture of Sublime Text since I don't have to press the shift or any other modifier in my keyboard distribution to get access to the "+" key, here you can see where is the "+" and the "=" keys:  https://i.imgur.com/zApufU1.png  anyways one way or another it is solved with the methodology you told me, thanks again.